# rosmake orocos_toolchain. Can i exclude orogen?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

im trying to crosscompile orocos_toolchain and rtt_ros_integration with rosmake.
Can i exclude orogen from the rosmake? How? Im searching thru' makefiles but i find nothing.

Thanks for the help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64130/rosmake-orocos_toolchain.-can-i-exclude-orogen?/) by [jorcoval](https://answers.ros.org/users/5030/jorcoval/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved with skip blacklist.

Thanks

---

Originally posted by [jorcoval](https://answers.ros.org/users/5030/jorcoval/) with karma: 16 on 2013-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0